# Trub versus Lees

Tags: trub, lees

What is the difference between Trub and Lees?

I've only heard about lees in regards to wine, i.e. the leftovers in the bottle. Note, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lees_(fermentation)) Lees is not only leftover grape bits, but also dead yeast.

OTH, Trub is the leftovers after a homebrew boil. I've also heard the settled yeast after bottle conditioning called trub.

Could the bottle conditioning 'trub' also be called 'lees'? Is there a technical difference? Is there an etymological difference? (I realize that last question might be better fit for the ELL or English stacks, please advise)

Answer (score 2):

Wiki says that trub is German for lees.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trub_(brewing)